# Select an anchor in a hover state with the child div

Tags: jquery, select

I have an anchor tag nested in a container, and a `div` nested inside the anchor tag:

```
<div id="container">
<a href="" id="my-anchor"><div id="my-image"></div>Text of the link</a>
</div>
```

On hover over the text of the link of the anchor tag, the `div` is assigned a background image in CSS, which makes an image appear:

```
a#my-anchor:hover #my-image {
background: url('img/the-image.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
```

Using jQuery, I want to select inside the #container the anchor tag in the hover state with the child div that has the background. What's the proper way to do that?

**EDIT:** To rephrase it, I want that link selected, and the background image to appear, without a user hovering a cursor over it – just by having jQuery imitate the hover, probably via some workaround.

**EDIT # 2:** To rephrase it another way: I want the link text to have the same CSS as if it's hovered over, and the background image in the div to appear – but using jQuery, and without anyone hovering the cursor over the link.

Comment: jQuery does not support pseudo selectors, as they are not really part of the DOM. Just use the regular mouseenter/mouseleave events instead.

Comment: What would be the best workaround, @adeneo?

Comment: Maybe adding/removing a class .active could help(?)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too, @Claudio, but how do I add that class to exactly the right combination of elements? It has to be anchor tag inside the container, with the my-image div showing the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, you have probably something like this: `#my-anchor:hover {...`
Change it to:

```
#my-anchor:hover,
#my-anchor.active {
...
```

Now with JS, something like this:

```
$('#container').find('#my-anchor').addClass('active').delay(3000).removeClass('active')
// or just
$('#my-anchor').addClass('active').delay(3000).removeClass('active')
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, @Claudio – thank you very much! - but is there a way to make it more generic? Using only a and div, instead of id names? (The only name that could be used is the id of the container).

Comment: Another (bigger) problem, @Claudio, that what you're suggesting makes the link look active, but it doesn't add the background image to the div – because in my CSS it's #my-anchor:hover #my-image, not just #my-anchor:hover. How can this be solved?

Comment: With class names (they don't need to be unique like ID's). `<div id="container" class="container-box">
<a href="" id="my-anchor" class="anchor"><div id="my-image"></div>...</a>
</div>`

Comment: The same way, just add the child element to the CSS: `#my-anchor:hover #my-image, #my-anchor.active #my-image { .... `

Comment: Is it correct syntax to do something like this: $('#container').find('a') – @Claudio?

Comment: Yes, but it will find any <a> inside #container (just keep that in mind)

Comment: Selecting any anchor tag is fine, @Claudio. But the next question is: how do I say: "inside the #container, find a and add the .active class to it, and also show the background image of the div inside the `a`? You're saying, this can be done by adding #my-anchor.active #my-image - but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: P.S. the link selected with jQuery has a slight glow around it, @Claudio.

Comment: Solved it, @Claudio. Thank you for your help!